# Magento 2 : How to make/call section ajax to show popup after cart update?

Tags: magento2, addtocart, section

I want to make a new section popup like minicart. And need to update that on any cart action like addtocart, delete item from cart. For this I am thinking to make a section ajax call. How can I do this ?